# Sorting sibling elements in XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

Assume the following XML input -

```
<parent>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <name>Alice</name>
    <another-attribute>something</another-attribute>
    <city>Kansas City</city>
    <city>Atlanta</city>
</parent>
```

How do i sort the homogeneous attributes alphabetically? In other words, here is the expected output-

```
<parent>
    <name>Alice</name>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <another-attribute>something</another-attribute>
    <city>Atlanta</city>
    <city>Kansas City</city>
</parent>
```

I was able to get some of the more complicated sorting done with various examples in stackoverflow, but i am struggling this one.

Disclaimer: I am an XSLT noob, so please go easy on abuses.

Comment: How generic do you need this to be? It is very simple to sort each property individually, by applying templates to it explicitly by name. Otherwise this becomes a grouping question.

Comment: What happened if there were another `<name>Albert</name>` after for instance the `city` elements? Would you want it to move in front of the other `name` elements?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Indeed. It would be ideal if "Albert" is moved ahead of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using `for-each`es with `xsl:sort`.
In the below code the `for-each` selects all `name` nodes and sorts them by its `text()` content. Same for `city` elements respectively. The `xsl:copy-of` in the middle copies all other elements that are not `name` or `city` elements themselves.

The `xsl:copy` in the beginning copies the current selected element which is `parent` and the following `xsl:copy-of` copies its (possible) attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="parent">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:for-each select="name">
          <xsl:sort select="text()" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::name | self::city)]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="city">
          <xsl:sort select="text()" />
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```